# how akka frontend node connect to cluster after restarting all down backend nodes?

Tags: akka, cluster-computing, frontend, backend, seed

take the official example [akka-sample-cluster-java](https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.5/akka-sample-cluster-java) for demonstration:
1. firstly, start frontend node

```
sbt 'runMain sample.cluster.factorial.FactorialFrontendMain'
```

2. start tow backend nodes which are also seed nodes separately

```
sbt 'runMain sample.cluster.factorial.FactorialBackendMain 2551'
sbt 'runMain sample.cluster.factorial.FactorialBackendMain 2551'
```

Everything should be fine for now.

```
[info] [INFO] [05/11/2017 17:40:42.822] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] - Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] is JOINING, roles [backend]
[info] [INFO] [05/11/2017 17:40:43.349] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] - Leader is moving node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] to [Up]
[info] [INFO] [05/11/2017 17:40:43.349] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] - Leader is moving node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552] to [Up]
[info] [INFO] [05/11/2017 17:40:43.349] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node     
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] - Leader is moving node         
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:56431] to [Up]
```

However, when I stopped both of the two backend nodes (by ctrl + c), and restarted them again, the status of either backend node is always "joining", and can't be changed to "up".

```
[info] [INFO] [05/11/2017 17:39:32.356] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] - Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] is JOINING, roles [backend]
[info] [INFO] [05/11/2017 17:39:35.637] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem)] Cluster Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551] - Node 
[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:56431] is JOINING, roles [frontend]
```

how can the frontend node join seeds nodes automatically without restarting frontend node? It works when restarting frontend node.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a cluster is formed, nodes in the cluster will stop looking for (other) seed nodes: seed nodes are only used for the initial formation of the cluster.

If you want to restart the 'backend' nodes in this example and have them join the already-running 'frontend' node, then the 'backend' nodes will have to initiate the connection to the 'frontend' node, not vice versa. In other words: the 'frontend' node then acts as the seed node for these newly started backend nodes.

In this sample this is a bit tricky because the 'frontend' node is not listening on a predictable port number.

If you make adjustments to make this possible, keep in mind that this example uses 'auto-downing' as a downing strategy. This means that when the cluster leader cannot reach a node for a while, it will mark that node as (permanently) 'down'. Even when the node returns, it can no longer join the cluster with its original address, which is now permanently banned from the cluster (to prevent certain undefined behavior and 'split brain' problems).

Note that in production you likely wouldn't use auto-downing, but run a tool that can look at your nodes 'from the outside' and decide which nodes to consider merely 'unreachable' and which to permanently decommission.

Comment: appreciated for your answer!